# Obtain image from scanner device using Flutter windows

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to obtain image from scanner device connected to pc using flutter? I searched all web and couldn’t find any answers about this , any helpful ideas? I have a windows application and I am  stuck on this point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.